# Update two tables using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi how can i update a values in two tables my code as shown as below cases:

```
public function subscriberprofileupdate($ids, Request $request) {
    $profile = Subscriberinfo::find($ids); 
    $id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $user_id = \Auth::user()->user_id;
    $subscriber_id = \Auth::user()->subscriber_id;
    $inputteacher = $request->all();

    $profile->contact_person_firstname = $inputteacher['contact_person_firstname'];
    $profile->contact_person_lastname = $inputteacher['contact_person_lastname'];
    $profile->email = $inputteacher['email'];
    $profile->save();
    return Redirect('/subscriber/profile');
}
```

If i can update email in subscriber table means that it will also update on users table also by using the user_id.
How can i make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply:

```
User::where('id',$user_id)->update(['email' => $inputteacher['email']]);
```

It will update the `Users` table email field where `users.id` is `$user_id`

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to add a new column named **user_id** in your subscriber table  and you than you can fetch the data if you have given proper relation in your model.

Comment: user_id is also to be there users tables.we can fetch the user_id value from users tables itself.

Answer (score 0):

When updating a belongsTo relationship, you may use the [associate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) method.

*For example:*

```
$inputteacher = $request->all();
$userdetail = User::find(1);
$userdetail->firstname = $inputteacher['contact_person_firstname'];
$userdetail->lastname = $inputteacher['contact_person_lastname'];

$profile = Subscriberinfo::find($ids);
$profile->contact_person_firstname = $inputteacher['contact_person_firstname'];
$profile->contact_person_lastname = $inputteacher['contact_person_lastname'];
$userdetail->profiles()->save($profile);

//This will save not only a model, but also all of its relationships
$userdetail->push();
```

Comment: @Nishanth I suggest you to use this approach for `belongsTo` relationship.